# ASyncTask not starting when using it for the 2nd time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, youtube-data-api

I have the following ASyncTask:

```
public class RetrieveSearchResultsTask extends AsyncTask<YouTube.Search.List, Void, ArrayList<SearchResult>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<SearchResult> doInBackground(YouTube.Search.List... searchListByKeywordRequest) {
        try {
            SearchListResponse response = searchListByKeywordRequest[0].execute();
            ArrayList<SearchResult> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();
            for(SearchResult sr : response.getItems()){
                searchResults.add(sr);
            }
            return searchResults;
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("error",e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

The call to the ASyncTask is the following (the code is in another activity):

```
AsyncTask<YouTube.Search.List, Void, ArrayList<SearchResult>> task = new RetrieveSearchResultsTask().execute(searchListByKeywordRequest);
            ArrayList<SearchResult> searchResults = task.get();
```

This ASyncTask is retrieving search results using the youtube api.
Now, the first time I search it works perfectly, but when I try to search again, the application get stuck on the following code:

```
ArrayList<SearchResult> searchResults = task.get();
```

and the screen just turns black and the app stops responding.

I would really appreciate if someone helped me understand what is the problem

Comment: First of all, check the `logcat` for error's. It can be anything may be your app doing long work over main thread or null pointer exception or anything else. So, check `logcat` and post error. `Please help me` not works here bro, you have to post error's.

Comment: You need to create a new AsyncTask task every time. Refer to [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) wherein it is mentioned that "**The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)**"

Comment: @HeisenBrg No errors in logcat

Comment: @YogeshM There is no such error in my logcat

Comment: From your code, you need `AsyncTask<YouTube.Search.List, Void, ArrayList<SearchResult>> task = new RetrieveSearchResultsTask().execute(searchListByKeywordRequest);
            ArrayList<SearchResult> searchResults = task.get();` every time to fetch results.

Comment: @YogeshM I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: I meant, every time you want to fetch results you should create new AsyncTask `AsyncTask<YouTube.Search.List, Void, ArrayList<SearchResult>> task = new RetrieveSearchResultsTask().execute(searchListByKeywordRequest);` and the fetch results `ArrayList<SearchResult> searchResults = task.get();`. I can only deduce this from the available information.

Comment: Also you need to implement `AsyncTask::onPostExecute(Result)`. No point in executing task in another thread and waiting for result (unless you are not in UI thread in first place).

Comment: @YogeshM That's exactly what I did in my code...

Comment: Your question implies otherwise. Anyway I can't see anything wrong in what you've shown; problem might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask instances can only be used one time.

Instead, just call your task like new MyAsyncTask().execute("");

**From the AsyncTask API docs:**

Threading rules
There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class to work properly:

The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
**The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)**

Comment: I do call my task the way you mentioned, and I don't get any exception